# Expressive template of rope with more than 5 arguments failing to inline properly

Tags: c++, templates, optimization

I been experimenting a little with expressive templates and rope data structures to try and see what kind of gains can be achieved. So far it is working quite nicely. However, when attempting to concatenate more than 5 arguments together the compiler fails to optimize properly and generates unnecessary temporaries. Could someone enlighten me why this is happening? Is it a compiler limitation or do my optimization options require tweaking?

I am using g++ 4.4.1 (mingw32) with the following options: -O3 -Winline -Wextra -Wall -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fomit-frame-pointer -fexpensive-optimizations -fverbose-asm -S

The code is below, it is just an experimentation so it does not really follow any standards:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename Derived>
struct rope_base {
    const Derived & ref() const;
};

struct string {
    size_t m_length;
    char * m_value;

    template<typename Derived>
    string(const rope_base<Derived> & rope);
    ~string();

    const char * data() const;
    size_t length() const;
    char * write_to(char * dst) const;
};

struct static_string {
    const char * m_value;
    const size_t m_length;

    static_string(const char * value);

    size_t length() const;
    char * write_to(char * dst) const;
};

template<typename T>
struct rope_traits {
    typedef const T type;
};

template<>
struct rope_traits<string> {
    typedef const string & type;
};

template<>
struct rope_traits<static_string> {
    typedef const static_string & type;
};

template<typename Left, typename Right>
struct rope : public rope_base<rope<Left, Right> > {
    typename rope_traits<Left>::type m_left;
    typename rope_traits<Right>::type m_right;

    rope(const Left & left, const Right & right);

    size_t length() const;
    char * write_to(char * dst) const;
};

inline static_string::static_string(const char * value)
: m_value(value)
, m_length(__builtin_strlen(m_value)) {}

inline size_t static_string::length() const {
    return m_length;
}

inline char * static_string::write_to(char * dst) const {
    __builtin_memcpy(dst, m_value, m_length);
    return dst + m_length;
}

template<typename Derived>
inline string::string(const rope_base<Derived> & rope)
: m_length(rope.ref().length())
, m_value(new char[m_length + 1]) {
    *rope.ref().write_to(m_value) = 0;
}

inline string::~string() {
    delete[] m_value;
}

inline const char * string::data() const {
    return m_value;
}

inline size_t string::length() const {
    return m_length;
}

template<typename Derived>
inline const Derived & rope_base<Derived>::ref() const {
    return static_cast<const Derived &>(*this);
}

template<typename Left, typename Right>
inline rope<Left, Right>::rope(const Left & left, const Right & right)
: m_left(left)
, m_right(right) {}

template<typename Left, typename Right>
inline size_t rope<Left, Right>::length() const {
    return m_left.length() + m_right.length();
}

template<typename Left, typename Right>
inline char * rope<Left, Right>::write_to(char * dst) const {
    return m_right.write_to(m_left.write_to(dst));
}

inline rope<static_string, static_string> operator+(const static_string & left, const static_string & right) {
    return rope<static_string, static_string>(left, right);
}

template<typename Left>
inline rope<Left, static_string> operator+(const rope_base<Left> & left, const static_string & right) {
    return rope<Left, static_string>(left.ref(), right);
}

template<typename Right>
inline rope<static_string, Right> operator+(const static_string & left, const rope_base<Right> & right) {
    return rope<static_string, Right>(left, right.ref());
}

template<typename Left, typename Right>
inline rope<Left, Right> operator+(const rope_base<Left> & left, const rope_base<Right> & right) {
    return rope<Left, Right>(left.ref(), right.ref());
}

typedef static_string ss;

int main(int, char **)
{
    // works up to 5
    string s(ss("111111111111") + "222222222222" + "333333333333" + "444444444444" + "555555555555");
    printf("%d %s\n", s.length(), s.data());
    return 0;
}
```

The code above generates quite nice assembler output which is fully inlined and all arguments have been reduced to constants:

```
.def    ___main;    .scl    2;    .type    32;    .endef
.section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
.ascii "444444444444\0"
LC1:
.ascii "333333333333\0"
LC2:
.ascii "222222222222\0"
LC3:
.ascii "111111111111\0"
LC4:
.ascii "555555555555\0"
LC5:
.ascii "%d %s\12\0"
.text
.p2align 2,,3
.globl _main
.def    _main;    .scl    2;    .type    32;    .endef
_main:
pushl    %ebp     #
movl    %esp, %ebp     #,
andl    $-16, %esp     #,
pushl    %edi     #
pushl    %esi     #
pushl    %ebx     #
subl    $20, %esp     #,
call    ___main     #
movl    $LC3, %esi     #, D.2495
movl    $61, (%esp)     #,
call    __Znaj     #
movl    %eax, %ebx     #, D.3126
movl    $3, %ecx     #, tmp74
movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3126, D.3125
rep movsl
leal    12(%eax), %eax     #, D.3180
movb    $3, %cl     #,
movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3180, D.3180
movl    $LC2, %esi     #, D.2496
rep movsl
leal    24(%ebx), %eax     #, D.3186
movb    $3, %cl     #,
movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3186, D.3186
movl    $LC1, %esi     #, D.2502
rep movsl
leal    36(%ebx), %eax     #, D.3192
movb    $3, %cl     #,
movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3192, D.3192
movl    $LC0, %esi     #, D.2539
rep movsl
leal    48(%ebx), %eax     #, D.3198
movl    $LC4, %esi     #, tmp87
movb    $3, %cl     #,
movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3198, D.3198
rep movsl
movb    $0, 12(%eax)     #,
movl    %ebx, 8(%esp)     # D.3126,
movl    $60, 4(%esp)     #,
movl    $LC5, (%esp)     #,
call    _printf     #
testl    %ebx, %ebx     # D.3126
je    L2     #,
movl    %ebx, (%esp)     # D.3126,
call    __ZdaPv     #
L2:
xorl    %eax, %eax     #
addl    $20, %esp     #,
popl    %ebx     #
popl    %esi     #
popl    %edi     #
leave
ret
.def    __Znaj;    .scl    2;    .type    32;    .endef
.def    _printf;    .scl    2;    .type    32;    .endef
.def    __ZdaPv;    .scl    2;    .type    32;    .endef
```

Inlining fails when adding one or more parameters to the concatenation, resulting in temporaries being copied around and parameters being treated as variables:

```
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;    .type    32;    .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
    .ascii "777777777777\0"
LC1:
    .ascii "666666666666\0"
LC2:
    .ascii "555555555555\0"
LC3:
    .ascii "444444444444\0"
LC4:
    .ascii "333333333333\0"
LC5:
    .ascii "222222222222\0"
LC6:
    .ascii "111111111111\0"
LC7:
    .ascii "888888888888\0"
LC8:
    .ascii "%d %s\12\0"
    .text
    .p2align 2,,3
.globl _main
    .def    _main;    .scl    2;    .type    32;    .endef
_main:
    pushl    %ebp     #
    movl    %esp, %ebp     #,
    andl    $-16, %esp     #,
    pushl    %edi     #
    pushl    %esi     #
    pushl    %ebx     #
    subl    $228, %esp     #,
    call    ___main     #
    movl    $LC0, 168(%esp)     #, D.2650.m_value
    movl    $12, 172(%esp)     #, D.2650.m_length
    movl    $LC1, 176(%esp)     #, D.2613.m_value
    movl    $12, 180(%esp)     #, D.2613.m_length
    movl    $LC2, 184(%esp)     #, D.2576.m_value
    movl    $12, 188(%esp)     #, D.2576.m_length
    movl    $LC3, 192(%esp)     #, D.2539.m_value
    movl    $12, 196(%esp)     #, D.2539.m_length
    movl    $LC4, 200(%esp)     #, D.2502.m_value
    movl    $12, 204(%esp)     #, D.2502.m_length
    movl    $LC5, 208(%esp)     #, D.2496.m_value
    movl    $12, 212(%esp)     #, D.2496.m_length
    movl    $LC6, 216(%esp)     #, D.2495.m_value
    movl    $12, 220(%esp)     #, D.2495.m_length
    leal    216(%esp), %eax     #, tmp78
    movl    %eax, 152(%esp)     # tmp78, D.2571.m_left.m_left.m_left
    leal    208(%esp), %eax     #, tmp79
    movl    %eax, 156(%esp)     # tmp79, D.2571.m_left.m_left.m_right
    leal    200(%esp), %eax     #, tmp80
    movl    %eax, 160(%esp)     # tmp80, D.2571.m_left.m_right
    leal    192(%esp), %eax     #, tmp81
    movl    %eax, 164(%esp)     # tmp81, D.2571.m_right
    leal    132(%esp), %edi     #, tmp82
    leal    152(%esp), %esi     #, tmp83
    movl    $4, %ecx     #, tmp84
    rep movsl
    leal    184(%esp), %eax     #, tmp85
    movl    %eax, 148(%esp)     # tmp85, D.2608.m_right
    leal    108(%esp), %edi     #, tmp86
    leal    132(%esp), %esi     #, tmp87
    movb    $5, %cl     #,
    rep movsl
    leal    176(%esp), %eax     #, tmp89
    movl    %eax, 128(%esp)     # tmp89, D.2645.m_right
    leal    80(%esp), %edi     #, tmp90
    leal    108(%esp), %esi     #, tmp91
    movb    $6, %cl     #,
    rep movsl
    leal    168(%esp), %eax     #, tmp93
    movl    %eax, 104(%esp)     # tmp93, D.2682.m_right
    leal    48(%esp), %edi     #, tmp94
    leal    80(%esp), %esi     #, tmp95
    movb    $7, %cl     #,
    rep movsl
    movl    48(%esp), %ebx     # D.2719.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_left, SR.35
    movl    52(%esp), %edx     # D.2719.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_right, SR.34
    movl    56(%esp), %eax     # D.2719.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_right,
    movl    %eax, 36(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    60(%esp), %eax     # D.2719.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_right,
    movl    %eax, 32(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    64(%esp), %eax     # D.2719.m_left.m_left.m_left.m_right,
    movl    %eax, 28(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    68(%esp), %eax     # D.2719.m_left.m_left.m_right,
    movl    %eax, 24(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    72(%esp), %eax     # D.2719.m_left.m_right,
    movl    %eax, 20(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    4(%ebx), %eax     # <variable>.m_length, tmp97
    addl    4(%edx), %eax     # <variable>.m_length, tmp97
    addl    $12, %eax     #,
    movl    %eax, 44(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    36(%esp), %eax     # %sfp,
    movl    4(%eax), %eax     # <variable>.m_length,
    addl    %eax, 44(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    32(%esp), %eax     # %sfp,
    movl    4(%eax), %eax     # <variable>.m_length,
    addl    %eax, 44(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    28(%esp), %eax     # %sfp,
    movl    4(%eax), %eax     # <variable>.m_length,
    addl    %eax, 44(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    24(%esp), %eax     # %sfp,
    movl    4(%eax), %eax     # <variable>.m_length,
    addl    %eax, 44(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    20(%esp), %eax     # %sfp,
    movl    4(%eax), %eax     # <variable>.m_length,
    addl    %eax, 44(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    44(%esp), %eax     # %sfp, tmp105
    incl    %eax     # tmp105
    movl    %eax, (%esp)     # tmp105,
    movl    %edx, 16(%esp)     #,
    call    __Znaj     #
    movl    %eax, 40(%esp)     #, %sfp
    movl    (%ebx), %esi     # <variable>.m_value, <variable>.m_value
    movl    4(%ebx), %ecx     # <variable>.m_length, <variable>.m_length
    movl    %eax, %edi     #, D.3662
    rep movsb
    movl    40(%esp), %eax     # %sfp, D.3735
    addl    4(%ebx), %eax     # <variable>.m_length, D.3735
    movl    16(%esp), %edx     #,
    movl    (%edx), %esi     # <variable>.m_value, <variable>.m_value
    movl    4(%edx), %ecx     # <variable>.m_length, <variable>.m_length
    movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3735, D.3735
    rep movsb
    addl    4(%edx), %eax     # <variable>.m_length, D.3741
    movl    36(%esp), %edx     # %sfp,
    movl    (%edx), %esi     # <variable>.m_value, <variable>.m_value
    movl    4(%edx), %ecx     # <variable>.m_length, <variable>.m_length
    movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3741, D.3741
    rep movsb
    addl    4(%edx), %eax     # <variable>.m_length, D.3747
    movl    32(%esp), %edx     # %sfp,
    movl    (%edx), %esi     # <variable>.m_value, <variable>.m_value
    movl    4(%edx), %ecx     # <variable>.m_length, <variable>.m_length
    movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3747, D.3747
    rep movsb
    addl    4(%edx), %eax     # <variable>.m_length, D.3753
    movl    28(%esp), %edx     # %sfp,
    movl    (%edx), %esi     # <variable>.m_value, <variable>.m_value
    movl    4(%edx), %ecx     # <variable>.m_length, <variable>.m_length
    movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3753, D.3753
    rep movsb
    addl    4(%edx), %eax     # <variable>.m_length, D.3759
    movl    24(%esp), %edx     # %sfp,
    movl    (%edx), %esi     # <variable>.m_value, <variable>.m_value
    movl    4(%edx), %ecx     # <variable>.m_length, <variable>.m_length
    movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3759, D.3759
    rep movsb
    addl    4(%edx), %eax     # <variable>.m_length, D.3765
    movl    20(%esp), %edx     # %sfp,
    movl    (%edx), %esi     # <variable>.m_value, <variable>.m_value
    movl    4(%edx), %ecx     # <variable>.m_length, <variable>.m_length
    movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3765, D.3765
    rep movsb
    addl    4(%edx), %eax     # <variable>.m_length, D.3771
    movl    $LC7, %esi     #, tmp148
    movb    $3, %cl     #,
    movl    %eax, %edi     # D.3771, D.3771
    rep movsl
    movb    $0, 12(%eax)     #,
    movl    40(%esp), %eax     # %sfp,
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)     #,
    movl    44(%esp), %edx     # %sfp,
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)     #,
    movl    $LC8, (%esp)     #,
    call    _printf     #
    movl    40(%esp), %eax     # %sfp,
    testl    %eax, %eax     #
    je    L2     #,
    movl    40(%esp), %eax     # %sfp,
    movl    %eax, (%esp)     #,
    call    __ZdaPv     #
L2:
    xorl    %eax, %eax     #
    addl    $228, %esp     #,
    popl    %ebx     #
    popl    %esi     #
    popl    %edi     #
    leave
    ret
    .def    __Znaj;    .scl    2;    .type    32;    .endef
    .def    _printf;    .scl    2;    .type    32;    .endef
    .def    __ZdaPv;    .scl    2;    .type    32;    .endef
```

Comment: Have you tested whether -finline-limit=<some large n> gives you the desired output? I suspect you just hit the default limit.

Comment: I have considered that I was hitting some limitation. Doing some testing with -finline-limit set between 1000 - 10000000 yields no change. Since I have enabled -Winline, setting it too low (-finline-limit=100) causes warnings regarding inline failures.

Comment: I presume adding __attribute__((always_inline)) does give you the desired result? Do you not see any -Winline warnings?

Comment: No, unfortunately forcing inline on all the various methods and functions produces the same result. I'm guessing that g++ has difficult eliminating temporaries past a certain depth.

string s(ss("111111111111") + "222222222222" + ...

expands to a chain of calls as follows:

string(operator+(operator+(operator+(... static_string(""), static_string(""), static_string(""))))

Which generates several temporaries:
1) several static_strings through implicit conversion. This is intentional to ensure that the result of __builtin_strlen remains a constant and avoid rep scasb's from being emitted) ...

Comment: 2) several rope<Left,Rights>'s that hold references to these static_strings. These are all on the stack and must be copied by value as the stack space where they sit on will have been reclaimed by the time they are needed.

I am guessing that g++ has problems handling the recursive calls to a certain depth and can no longer eliminate these temporaries. Basically, it seems to be unable to see through all the constructor calls if they are stacked high enough (like class(class(class(class(class(1))))) ).

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case. I quickly tested without the dynamic allocation (using a fixed sized char buf instead of the heap allocated buffer) and the assembly is nicely collapsed. I also get -Winline warnings (when using heap) that seem to indicate gcc is mispredicting here.

Comment: Interestingly, I cannot reproduce your result. Even removing the rope.ref().length() call and replacing *rope.ref().write_to(m_value) = 0 with rope.ref().write_to(NULL) still fails to collapse properly. Only when I remove this call entirely the compiler wakes up and decides that I am doing a printf("%d %s\n", 0, NULL). What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: Interesting. I'm on g++ 4.7.2, same options.

Comment: I guess something changed between 4.4.1 and 4.7.2. After updating my mingw package, your results are reproducible. Using default compiler optimizations and liberally sprinkling around always_inline attributes, everything inlines nicely even with 9 arguments.

Regarding the fixed buffer, it is the new operator itself that generates dog ugly output. It is generating entire prologues everywhere it is used. Perhaps I should just start using malloc again?

For now I'll accept your answer since it did answer my original question.

Comment: I created an answer just to make the conversation a bit clearer. What you use depends what you are trying to achieve. The more knowledge you have at compile time, the more inlining you can get. In terms of inlining, calling malloc is not really different to wrapping new() in a seperate function.

Answer (score 1):

A few things (per the discussion in comments):

Upgrade your gcc. A lot of optimisation improvements were made in the 4.6 series, including some improvements to inlining.

With a newer gcc -Winline warns that your string constructor will not be inlined:

```
warning: inlining failed in call to 'string::string(const rope_base<Derived>&) [with Derived = rope<rope<rope<rope<rope<static_string, static_string>, static_string> static_string>, static_string>, static_string>]': call is unlikely and code size would grow [-Winline]
```

I'm not quite sure why gcc gives this particular message (which is usually pretty clearly related to an inline call in an unlikely branch), but the root of the problem is the call to new() in that constructor. Using a static fixed size buffer produces nice compact asm. Using malloc, or wrapping new in a non-inlined function call allows the constructor (but not malloc/function) to be inlined.

Which approach to take really depends on your specific use case. If the length of the strings could be known at compile time, or given a maximum value, as in your example, you can obviously completely inline. In the general case though, you are always going to have to give something up.

Comment: I've actually narrowed down the huge code expansion to the autovectorizer. For unknown reason, the new operator decided to zero-initialize string::m_value. The autovectorizer sees a loop going from zero to N (total length of concatenation) and decides to vectorize the loop. Disabling the autovectorizer with -fno-tree-vectorize results in a more reasonable sequence of a single loop consisting of a couple mov's, cmp and jne's. I fail to see why the zero-initialization happens and how to prevent or disable it.

Comment: Replying to myself, think I found a syntax limitation. m_value(new [m_length + 1]) is interpreted as m_value = new [m_length + 1](). The trailing parenthesis cause the resulting array to be initialized. I found a workaround by moving the call to new into a small, inlined function. It is still necessary to use  __attribute__((always_inline)) but that is something I can live with. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Interesting - I didn't expect value initialisation there. I didn't follow why that would lead to your problem though?

Comment: Not originally no, the problem in my question was due to using an outdated version of g++ that was simply unable to fold all the temporaries properly.

However, after updating g++ still failed to generate optimal code due to unexpected initialization of the destination buffer being allocated in the string constructor.

The generated initialization loop was subsequently vectorized by the autovectorizer. The end result was far from optimal as the initialization block was actually larger than concatenating 9 strings!

Moving the new operator solved my follow-up problem.

Comment: I should probably file a bug report. The difference between new <type>[] and new <type>[]() is syntactically clear and does not seem to be respected in this case. It could be a standards thing though, where initialization might be required in this case, regardless of syntax. Still, it is confusing and -Wall should have at least omitted some warning due to implicit initialization.

Answer (score 0):

As jmetcalfe's cleared up, the reason why g++ failed to fold all the temporaries properly was due to an outdated version of g++. Upgrading from 4.4.1 to 4.7.2 resolved this issue. g++'s changelogs most likely contain information regarding which bug I was triggering or which optimization has been added to generate correct results.